# Using an image in SVG when embedded as background-image

Tags: image, svg, background, encode

If you want to use a bitmap image inside an SVG that is going to be embedded as a background-image, you have to encode the bitmap. Otherwise it won't load.

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="700" height="700" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,..." />
```

Or within a pattern:

```
<pattern id="pattern1" x="0" y="0" width="700" height="700" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
        <image x="0" y="0" width="700" height="700" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,..." />
</pattern>
```

Is there any simpler way without the need of encoding?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: I know this isn't a question but I could KISS YOU, sir. Solved a problem I've been trying to work out for  a week.